# Merge 2 different git repos, from Heroku to GitHub

Tags: git, github, heroku

I have a local `git` repo and a remote one on `Heroku`. They are in sync. I am now added as a contributor to a `GitHub` repo that contains a couple of files in it.

How do I push my local (or `Heroku`) repo to the dev branch of this new `GitHub` repo that I don't own? I don't want to overwrite or delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your local `git` repository, [add a remote repository](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) that points to the `GitHub` repository:

   ```
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo.git
   ```
2. Create a branch in your local `git` repository to stage the merge you're about to do:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git pull origin master
   git checkout -b feature/merge-local-to-remote
   ```
3. Perform a pull of the remote repository into your local copy, which will generate merge conflicts for any local `git` files that also exist in the `GitHub` repository:

   ```
   git pull upstream master
   ```
4. Fix any merge conflicts that arise, making sure not to overwrite anything found in the `GitHub` repo that you want to preserve. Then, commit all changes back to your local merge branch:

   ```
   git add <the files you want to push to GitHub>
   git commit -m "fixing merge conflicts from upstream"
   ```
5. Push your branch to the `GitHub` repo as a branch:

   ```
   git push upstream feature/merge-local-to-remote
   ```

Create a pull request via the GitHub UI and verify that all of your `git` repo's contents made it to `GitHub` without overwriting anything.